# Cannot route to page using blazor route with parameter

Tags: parameters, routes, blazor

I have an issue with routing in my blazor server side app. I have specified `@page "/intent/{intentid:int}"` in my razor view and I am using a link tag to navigate to it on the side bar ex: Test. the address bar url changes on link click but my intent c# code behind OnInit is not being fired ??? any suggestions ?

I've tried using **UriHelper** to navigate to the page but again page **OnInit** doesn't get fired.

intent view:

```
@page "/"
@page "/intent/{intentid:int}"
```

intent code behind:

```
[Parameter]
private int IntentId { get; set; }
```

NavMenu page:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="Intent/@(item.Key)">@intentClassifier.Text</a>
```

I expect to hit the **OnInit** on my intent page once the a link is clicked and receive the parameter value for intentid.
but only url changes in the address bar and thats all

Comment: So I got the answer to my question on [link](https://gitter.im/aspnet/Blazor) by Kirk Woll.

so Blazor sees that the page responsible for this route doesn't change, and so OnInit will not fire (since the same page is handling the same route). I've run into this situation in my tab set component, and the way I solved it was to register a listener on IUriHelper:

Comment: protected override void OnInit()
{
    base.OnInit();

    UriHelper.OnLocationChanged += UriHelperOnOnLocationChanged;
}

public void Dispose()
{
    UriHelper.OnLocationChanged -= UriHelperOnOnLocationChanged;
}

Comment: private void UriHelperOnOnLocationChanged(object sender, string e)
{
  //handle rest here
}

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to override OnParametersSetAsync, this gets called when the parameters are changed.